# Using IN for multiple attribute with joinning two tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables like.

Book table

```
class BookData
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\TopBundle\Entity\AuthorData")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="authorId", referencedColumnName="authorId",onDelete="SET NULL")
 */

private $authorId;
```

Author table

```
class AuthorData
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",unique=true,nullable=true)
 */
private $authorId;
```

One book row can have multiple $authorID.

then,I would like to select the authors who has at least one book.

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
        "SELECT n.name FROM AcmeTopBundle:AuthorData a 
        INNER JOIN AcmeTopBundle:BookData b
        Where b.authorId IN b.authorId
            ");
```

however it says.

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 112: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS, got 'a'
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In" must be enclosed in parenthesis so it's not a valid syntax.

A better way to do this is to use [many to many bidirectional association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional) between book and author. Then you can use inner join to remove any books without author from the result.

```
select a from AcmeTopBundle:AuthorData a JOIN a.books
```

Comment: Thank you I can slove my problem,that's the information what I want.